# Capacity Expansion on PERCH700 RAID-10

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, raid10

I have Dell Poweredge R710 server with PERC H700 Integrated RAID controller. Currently there are 4 SAS 300GB disks in RAID-10 array exposing single volume of 600GB. Server is running VMware ESXi 5.1.

I have 4 new SAS 300GB disks that I would like to add to this server to gain ~ 1.2 TB RAID-10 volume.

I wonder if I can do this expansion without loosing data on existing disks? Ideally I would like to perform this online, but offline upgrade is acceptable as well.

Technical Guide seems to indicate (it's bit unclear) that it's not possible to expand RAID-10 array. Can anyone give me a hints what should be possible, or what is the best approach to take.

Also, if I manage to upgrade volume size, will VMware be able to expand it's datastore?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that is's not possible to expand RAID 10 volume.

In the end I created another RAID-10 volume and used VMware console to join this volume to existing one (increase on existing Datastore).